# Powershell or Cygwin one liner to validate a CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, cygwin

I want to quickly work out what lines in a CSV file are "wrong" that is:

- Missing Columns
- Incorrectly escaped data
- Incorrectly escaped separators

The following gets me partially there:

```
awk -F , 'NF == 11' <file
```

but does not deal with escaped separators etc. My exact format is:

- 1st line contains column headers
- Each line is comma separated
- Text is enclosed with "

Anything I can run in PowerShell or via CygWin would be great.